# Ошибка в работе с указателем

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

В программе массив должен заполниться числами от 0 до 9 и после этого, отсчитывая от указателя, (который, как известно, ссылается всегда на 1 элемент массива), вывести все значения на экран

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main()
{
    int t[10], *n ;
    n=&t;
    for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
        {   t[i]=i ;}
```

Как вывести на экран числа? Как надо дописать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас присутствует ошибка:  `n`   является указателем на первый элемент массива после желаемого присвоения, а `&t` это `указатель на массив`, поэтому присвоение  `n=&t;` поменяйте на  `n = t;` а для вывода

```
while (n != t + 10)
        std::cout << *n++ <<' ';
```

и в конце не забудьте возвращать нулевое значение и скобочки `функции main` закрыть:

```
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не ругайтесь, это фишка языка брать адрес у фиксированного массива. Нужно было просто исправить тип `n = (int *)(t);` или `n = (int * )(&t);` что одинаково для C.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
    n = t + i;       
    cout<<*n;
}
```

как это работает:

`t` = `t[0]`

`t + 1` = `t[1]`

`t + 2` = `t[2]`

и так далее

Comment: Нет. Не выходит. Ответ выше решил проблему

Comment: у меня работает....

Comment: у меня в программе вместо `n = &t` `n = t` вот и все